# Can I invoke functions in PhoneGap Pushwoosh

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I have function Called `SaveDateAndTime();`

This function store date and time inside my application in `Localstorage`,

But my question, when Pushwoosh notifications Occurred, can I invoke my function `SaveDateAndTime()` even  my application is *not running*? and save date and time in `LocalStorage`?

Please note :`SaveDateAndTime()` this function inside my application .

Answer (score 2):

When the application will be launched in response for user interaction with push notification your code will be running. You can use this function in your push notifications handler.